# EditText is not clickable inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a "has_groups_fragment" fragment, and it has an EditText element.
When I try to click on it, the keyboard is not responding.

the layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/has_groups"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ft_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchGroupsArea"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputGroupSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.86"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search a group..."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/magnifyingGlass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/groupsList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="407dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.52"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any advices?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "the keyboard is not responding" - Do you mean the keyboard crashes?

Comment: No, I mean that its not shows up...
I want the keyboard to show up so I can write to the EditText field.. :)

Comment: Can you post your manifest please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have forgotten to add this to your activity, in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<activity android:name="your_activity_name"
              ...
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
              ...>
```

[More information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Hey, 
This is a fragment, not an activity, so its not in the manifest.
BUT - I tried to add this line:
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
 to the onCreateView method in my fragment class, without success.. any other options?

Comment: you still need that line if you want any of the fragments to use soft input - activity is the one controlling the interaction with the OS, not fragments.

Comment: So to add this line to the parent activity of this fragment?

Comment: Ok, I added this. But the problem wasn't solved...  :(

Comment: Yes. It will allow anything contained withing that activity to get input.

Comment: so you have an input field, and when you click on it, nothing happens, right? do you see a cursor blinking in the textfield?

Comment: Indeed.. the cursor is blinking

Comment: try "adjustPan" as a value for that attribute, so it's android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: You are welcome, please don't forget to accept the main answer as a correct one. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following attribute is the problem:

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

When this is set to true for an `EditText` `View`, it allows text in the `EditText` to be selected, but it disallows editing of the text, which is why the keyboard doesn't show.

If you just want to allow normal copy/paste procedures, you don't need to set this.

Comment: I tried to remove this attribute, but the problem was not solved.. :(

Comment: also remove android:clickable="true"

Comment: Do you have any other `Views` which may be interfering, like a navigation drawer? I just tested the code you have posted, and that attribute was the only problem.

Comment: I changed the stateHidden to adjustPan like @notrix suggested and the problem was solved..
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both `android:clickable` and `android:textIsSelectable` attributes